# Adding items/records to combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox which I try to add records to, but the records arent showing.
Here is the relevant code:

```
...
    {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Country',
            emptyText: 'Select country',
            fields: [
                {name: 'Sweden', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Denmark', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Island', type: 'string'}, 
                {name: 'Finland', type: 'string'},
            ]           
        }...
```

I am not getting any errors, the records just wont show.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave is partially JSON. What language are you trying to program in? Your tags state javascript and the JSON example is technically invalid.

Comment: No specific language yet actually, I'm just trying to learn extjs, so I am trying different stuff. I found the way of adding items to a combobox on the internet, but I didn't know it was JSON. Is there a way to hardcode the values?

Comment: Try looking at the documentation here.

http://www.sencha.com/learn/combobox-faq/

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from the ExtJS Documentation:

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [
    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    //...
]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Basically what you need to do is tie a store to the combobox for it to display the data properly. In this case you can define your model in the store directly as "fields", and then by setting a displayField in the combobox, you choose which value to display.

Hope this helps.